# checking for truthiness on a numpy array but for 2 values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array such as

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(range(1, 10))
```

assuming that `x` is a 'timeseries'
I am testing for truthiness on 2 conditions, if `x` t is larger than 5 and `x` t-1 is larger than 5 at the same time

is there a more pythonic way to write this test:

```
np.where((x[1:] > 5) & (x[0:-1] > 5), 1, 0)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

I feel like calling `x[1:]` and `x[0:-1]` to get a lag value is kind of weird.

any better way?

thanks!

Comment: FYI: You don't need to use `where(...)`.  The expression `(x[1:] > 5) & (x[0:-1] > 5)` is a boolean array that you could probably use in place of the `where(...)` result, or, if you need integers, convert using the `.astype(int)` method: `((x[1:] > 5) & (x[0:-1] > 5)).astype(int)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser good point! thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call your expression "weird"; using shifted slices like that is pretty common in numpy code.  There is some inefficiency, because you are repeating the same comparison `len(x) - 1` times.  For a small array, it might not matter, but if in your actual code `x` can be much larger, you could do something like: `xgt5 = x > 5; result = xgt5[1:] & xgt5[:-1]`

Comment: Yes my real arrays are much larger. I tested for speed, and your solution is about 2times faster. I can accept it as the answer if you want to post it below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call your expression "weird"; using shifted slices like that is pretty common in numpy code. There is some inefficiency, because you are repeating the same comparison `len(x) - 1` times. For a small array, it might not matter, but if in your actual code `x` can be much larger, you could do something like:

```
xgt5 = x > 5
result = xgt5[1:] & xgt5[:-1]
```